# Angular 6 Kendo UI DatePicker error

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm getting a strange error when trying to extract the standard format Kendo ui date-picker date into a different format.

package.json;

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.1.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^3.2.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^3.4.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^3.0.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^2.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^3.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^3.1.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.4.1",
```

the .ts file;

```
import { IntlService } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
import { CalendarView } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';

fromDate: string;
```

the .html file;

```
  <label class="k-form-field">
      <span>Required From</span>
      <kendo-datepicker
      [(ngModel)]="fromDate" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
      [format]="'dd-MM-yyyy'"
      (valueChange)="onChangeFromDate($event)"
      [value]="value">
    </kendo-datepicker>
  </label>
```

the .ts function;

```
public onChangeFromDate(value: Date): void {
this.fromDate = this.intl.formatDate(value, 'd-MM-y');
}
```

Gives an error:
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance. Check http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/#toc-using-with-json for possible resolution."

It seems to be the assigning of this.fromDate causing the issue.

Has anyone seen this before?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: why do you want the fromDate to be a string?

Comment: I'm adding it as one of the parameters to a URL

Comment: Then you should parse it when you add it as a parameter. The `ngModel` expects a Date, not a string

Comment: Thanks. I've re-worked my code and all is good!